# How to use regexp in endswith() in conditional subsetting of pandas df column?

Tags: python, pandas, ends-with

I want to use `.endswith()` or regexp in conditional subsetting of `Sender name` column in my dataframe.

Dataframe `df` has two columns `Sender email`, `Sender name` which I will use to define a subsetting rule, to select all mail coming from a specific shop and specific email of this shop:

`df = df[(df["Sender name"]=="Shop_name"]) & (df["Sender email"]=="reply@shop.com")]`

- But then I figured out that there are also mails from `buy@shop.com`, `noreply@shop.com`, etc. Is there an any way to neatly introduce all this mailboxes into something like `*@shop.com` in the second condition?
- I tried using `endswith()`, but couldn't figure out how to make it work for `series` object. I figured out I may first form a list with all mails from the column, and then check if sending mailserver is in it with `pd.Series.isin`. But maybe there is something more elegant out there?

Comment: Your question boils down to ***"How to use regexp on subsetting of string column in pandas?"***

Comment: Of course, it would be useful to have a link to the guide, if it is already posted elsewhere, but if not - it would be wonderful to have it here!

Comment: There are [25 questions on using `.endswith` in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpandas%5D+endswith+is%3Aquestion)

Comment: Please skim the pandas doc on [string-handling methods for Series.str](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/series.html#string-handling). I don't know what you mean by claiming *"`endswith()` does not work for `series` object."* The doc clearly shows you it does. Please post an example of it not working, include a snippet of input dataframe, your code with regex and the output/error. If you're asking for help writing/debugging a regx then just say so - don't claim the method doesn't work without showing your regex.

Comment: I tried using `df["Sender name"].endswith(...)`, as I did not know about string-handling methods in pandas. Please, mark this question as a dupclicate, if it you consider it appropriate.

Comment: Ah. **You can't call string methods directly on a pandas string Series; you have to use the `.str` accessor**, so `df["Sender name"].str.endswith(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.endswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.endswith.html) or [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with regex - `$` for end of string and also escape `.` by `\` , because `.` is special regex value - any character:

```
df1 = df[(df["Sender name"]=="Shop_name"]) & (df["Sender email"].str.endswith("@shop.com"))]
```

Or:

```
df1 = df[(df["Sender name"]=="Shop_name"]) & (df["Sender email"].str.contains("@shop\.com$"))]
```

Comment: I notice that in Pandas 1.5.x, there is no regex option for `.endswith` but `.contains` will work. Should explicitly specify `regex=True`.  In the source code, you can wander around to see what they do.  I think implementation is using Python `re` `.search` method on a compiled string, so you could write your own list comprehension to do same work.

Answer (score 1):

#### Using `.query`

Since `pandas >= 0.25.0` we can use `.query` with pandas methods (`.eq` & `str.endswith`) and using the backtick (`) to query column names with spaces:

```
df.query('`Sender name`.eq("Shop_name") & `Sender email`.str.endswith("@shop.com")')
```

**Output**

```
       Sender email Sender name
2    reply@shop.com   Shop_name
3      buy@shop.com   Shop_name
4  noreply@shop.com   Shop_name
```

Example dataframe used:

```
# Example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Sender email':['ex@example.com', 'ex2@example.com', "reply@shop.com", "buy@shop.com", "noreply@shop.com"],
                   'Sender name': ['example', 'example', 'Shop_name', 'Shop_name', 'Shop_name']})

       Sender email Sender name
0    ex@example.com     example
1   ex2@example.com     example
2    reply@shop.com   Shop_name
3      buy@shop.com   Shop_name
4  noreply@shop.com   Shop_name
```